# Why $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = (1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2})...$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, products, infinite-product

If we allow some $g(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ such that $g(0) = 1$ and also some $f(x)$ where:

$$f(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} 1 - \frac{x^2}{\pi^2k^2}$$

Then it is said f and g are equal. But my question is, what are the specifics **besides** the fact that:

Both have the same value at $x=0$. Both have the same roots, and an infinite number of them of course.

I feel like those two criteria definitely don’t justify equality, so I would like to know what legitimately justifies it.

Comment: Concretely, yes. But, I want to understand why people insist that demonstrating the fact that they have the same roots and same value at x=0 justifies the equality, even though the legitimate proof is much more complicated. Is there something I’m missing? Thanks though.

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath: Having the same roots does not justify equality (you can multiply $g$ by an arbitrary non-zero function $e^h$. Without a concrete reference where *“it is said that f and g are equal”* or *“why people insist that demonstrating the fact that they have the same roots and same value at x=0 justifies the equality”* it is difficult to say more.